# How java stream works with immutable collections under the box

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

Let's looka at the snippet:

```java
List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(0, 100_000_000)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> res = numbers.stream()
        .map(num -> num / 2)    // create another update collection
        .filter(num -> num / 2 == 0)    // and another filtered collection
        .map(String::valueOf)   // and another updated collection
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In functional programming we operate with immutable objects only. So the big `numbers` collection is immutalbe.

When we create a stream and do smth with this collections, e.g. update modify every element. I have showed one `map` lambda. Is it correct, that under the box, stream creates another big collection with updated values and under `collect()` it creates another big final collections? Or internal behaviour is different?

What if I have e.g. 10 `map` lambdas and some `filter`. Is this mean that we have a new copy of the bit collection after each `map` or `filter`? Or, probably, stream creates mutable collection and update it every time?

And in general, is this efficient (I mean from the recource point of view) to use streams for the big collections, or it's better to use plain old `for` operator?

***P.S.** I am not talking about `parallel stream`, because in this snippet, I do not care about a time performance, but I care about a memory performance.*

Comment: Immutability doesn't seem relevant here; you're not updating every element, you're creating a new collection *(eventually)* of transformed input elements. (That's what map does.) One benefit of streams is avoiding intermediate state. There's not much benefit **here** because it's a single operation.

Answer (score 2):

No, streams generally do not need to store all elements in memory until a terminal operation that collects them. (There are exceptions to this like `.distinct()` and `.sorted()` that cannot work without keeping state.)

See [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html).

> A stream provides an interface to a sequenced set of values of a specific element type. However, streams don’t actually store elements; they are computed on demand.

> There are two static methods—[`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) and [`Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier))—that let you create a stream from a function. However, because elements are calculated on demand, these two operations can produce elements “forever.” This is what we call an infinite stream: a stream that doesn’t have a fixed size, as a stream does when we create it from a fixed collection.

And the package documentation for [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

> Intermediate operations are further divided into stateless and stateful operations. Stateless operations, such as filter and map, retain no state from previously seen element when processing a new element -- each element can be processed independently of operations on other elements. Stateful operations, such as distinct and sorted, may incorporate state from previously seen elements when processing new elements.

Comment: I know this. There is terminal operator in my snippet. I wonder what do we have under the map, where is updated values are stored? Initial collection is immutable. Looks like  stream creates a mutable copy of the collection or so.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I've updated my answer to address the aspect of memory.

Comment: Ok. Stream does not creates internal storage. But how does it compute it `on demand`, the initial collecitons is immutable, and in general case streams cannot predict the size of the final collection. This is my main point.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Generally intermediate methods like `map` and `filter` create new streams that produce changed values from the original source when iterated over. It only needs to store the operation to be applied, not the elements themselves.

Comment: I see. There're no intermediate collections or so. Each intermediate function creates a new stream and on terminal operator each elements goes throught all streams.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Note, however, that some operations _do_ keep intermediate state. That includes `sorted` and `distinct`, as those operations cannot work without remembering the elements that came before.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Yes, I've added an additional reference from the package documentation that states this.

Comment: @Slaw Good point. I've added that to the answer.